# Set custom metadata when audio is playing (Control Centrer iOS) from javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, ios, audio

I need to change artwork (in Control Center) when audio is playing from tag `<audio>` in my html-page. On android it's working by `navigator.mediaSession.metadata` (see code below), but on iOS it's not working. Do you have any idea to solve it?

```
  <script>
    if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
        navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
              title: 'Unforgettable',
              artist: 'Nat King Cole',
              album: 'The Ultimate Collection (Remastered)',
              artwork: [
                      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/96x96',   sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
                      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/128x128', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
                      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/192x192', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
                      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/256x256', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
                      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/384x384', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
                      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/512x512', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
                    ]
            });
        navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() {
          document.querySelector('audio').play();
        });
        navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function() {
          document.querySelector('audio').pause();
        });
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently (2018.04.07) it is not supported for iOS browsers. Chrome for Android is only browser which support media session API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API